# How to filter items with a custom select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a custom-built select dropdown. I have a list of items with associated data values. The entire list displays by default. When an option from the dropdown is selected, on those listed items should remain.

i.e.; Select **News and Media** and only the items with the class **news** should display.

```js
//dropdown
for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select-wrapper")) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger span"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});

//filter
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  const filter = document.querySelector("#filter");
  const articles = document.querySelectorAll(".article");

  filter.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.target.value != "") {
      for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
        if (articles[i].dataset.itemName == event.target.value) {
          articles[i].classList.remove("hidden-item");
        } else {
          articles[i].classList.add("hidden-item");
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
        articles[i].classList.remove("hidden-item");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden-item {
  display: none;
}

.custom__select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.custom__select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom__select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom__options {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #005fec;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
.custom__select.open .custom__options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: #fff;
}
.custom__option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 28px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.custom__option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
}
.custom__option.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.custom__option.selected::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* arrow */
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.arrow::before, .arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0.15rem;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}
.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}
.open .arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}
.open .arrow::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
    <div class="custom__select">
      <div class="custom__select-trigger"><span>Story Type</span>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__options" id="filter">
        <span class="custom__option selected" selected="">All</span>
        <span class="custom__option" value="news">News and Media</span>
        <span class="custom__option" value="analysis">Analysis</span>
        <span class="custom__option" value="press">Press Releases</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="list article news 2020" data-item-name="news">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 1</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 26, 2020</li>
        <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   
    <div class="list article news 2019" data-item-name="news">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 2</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> November 17, 2019</li>
        <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   
    <div class="list article analysis 2017" data-item-name="analysis">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 3</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 15, 2017</li>
        <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   
    <div class="list article analysis 2016" data-item-name="analysis">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 4</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> January 3, 2016</li>
        <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   
    <div class="list article press 2014" data-item-name="press">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 5</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 13, 2014</li>
        <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Aritcle Title</a></li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   
    <div class="list article press 2013" data-item-name="press">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 6</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 6, 2013</li>
        <li><strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a></li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way I'd go about things but I would make a filter function that runs each time an option is selected.

I also wouldn't use the value tag on spans, that's what data attributes are for.

```js
//dropdown
for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select-wrapper")) {
    dropdown.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
    });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
    option.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
            this.parentNode.querySelector(".custom__option.selected").classList.remove("selected");
            this.classList.add("selected");
            this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(".custom__select-trigger span").textContent = this.textContent;
      filter(this.dataset['value']);
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
        if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
            select.classList.remove("open");
        }
    }
});

// filter
function filter(className) {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list.article');
    
    for (const article of list) {
        article.classList.add('hidden-item');
        if (article.getAttribute('data-item-name') === className) {
              article.classList.remove('hidden-item');
      }
        
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden-item {
    display: none;
}

.custom__select {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.custom__select-trigger {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 22px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__options {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #005fec;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

.custom__select.open .custom__options {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
    color: #fff;
}

.custom__option {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 22px 0 28px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.custom__option:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
}

.custom__option.selected {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.custom__option.selected::before {
    content: "•";
    margin-left: -12px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

/* arrow */

.arrow {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 0.15rem;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow::before {
    left: -5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #394a6d;
}

.arrow::after {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
    left: -5px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
    left: -5px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
        <div class="custom__select">
            <div class="custom__select-trigger">
                <span>Story Type</span>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom__options" id="filter">
                <span class="custom__option selected">All</span> 
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="news">News and Media</span> 
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="analysis">Analysis</span>
        <span class="custom__option" data-value="press">Press Releases</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list article news 2020" data-item-name="news">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 1</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 26, 2020</li>
        <li>
            <strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="list article news 2019" data-item-name="news">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 2</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> November 17, 2019</li>
        <li>
            <strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> news</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="list article analysis 2017" data-item-name="analysis">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 3</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 15, 2017</li>
        <li>
            <strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="list article analysis 2016" data-item-name="analysis">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 4</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> January 3, 2016</li>
        <li>
            <strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Article Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> analysis</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="list article press 2014" data-item-name="press">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Company:</strong> Company 5</li>
        <li><strong>Start Date:</strong> March 13, 2014</li>
        <li>
            <strong>Title:</strong> <a href="#" target="_blank">Aritcle Title</a>
        </li>
        <li><strong>Type:</strong> press</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```